# Azure Function Schedule and Runs

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Azure function with a schedule of  "0 0 3 * * *"  but I see it runs sometimes more than once a day.  Is there a reason for that?  The schedule is supposed to be every day at 10PM (adjusted for date time offset)  Do I not have the schedule right? Run on start is set to FALSE.

[image]

EDIT: It should be noted that at one point I had deployed run on start to true, but had since corrected that and deployed multiple updates with run on start set to false.  If I click on of the runs shown in the function monitor log, one of each duplicate date entries shows run on startup as the reason for firing.  Again, I don't know how this could be as I've set that to false.

2020-11-05 02:58:43.961
Executing 'XXX' (Reason='Timer fired at 2020-11-05T02:58:43.9099679+00:00', Id=XXX)
Information
2020-11-05 02:58:43.979
Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: RunOnStartup

Comment: There is a binding configuration properties named `runOnStartup`, the function will be invoked when the runtime starts  if you set it `true` . Please check it first.

Comment: Thanks,  I made that mistake early on, and it is for sure set to false

Comment: Thanks,  but as stated before, my run on start is set to false.

Comment: Sorry for the long time searching... @Patrick Goode, Do you have another function in this function app and invoke timer trigger function? Or timer trigger function invoke another function in this function app?

Comment: Hi, thanks but this function is the only one in a function app

Comment: hi @DorisLv, I updated the question FYI, if that helps.  thanks

Comment: Hey, @Patrick Goode, I tried a lot of times, `runOnStartup` works fine. If you sure this field in `function.json` configure correctly,  the only reason I can imagine is that the runtime(function application) restarting.

Comment: Hi @DorisLv I tried setting runOnStartup to false in function.json.  When I go out of the file and reuturn, it is gone.  I'll keep trying other solutions.  Most days it runs just once. Thanks

Comment: Okay.. If you find other solution, please generate as an answer for us to refer. @Patrick Goode

Answer (score 0):

As we can see, the issue is exactly `RunOnStartup`. I just test set the value to true then to false, it works as the doc described. Try configure **Always On** in general settings.
[image]

---

Microsoft recommend against setting runOnStartup to true in production in their [documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#configuration).
[image]

[image]